# Extract shipping rate from Amazon Product API

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am developing a price comparison site for books sold in Amazon, and I want to calculate the estimated price with shipping rate included and display to the user.

I searched the Amazon API manual and cannot find a response group or item that mention about shipping rate, is there an item for that?

Comment: [Three years later] Any luck?

Comment: @Hajjat Any luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the shipping rate info via Amazon Product API.

The reason for that is, I guess, the fact that the shipping rate depends on several factors (methods of shipping, type of an Amazon user (prime user, for example), location of the user etc), which are unknown at the time of the product fetching via API.